# Can I create an array in p5.js to replace this code?

Tags: arrays, p5.js

I'm helping my child refine some code, and would appreciate some help. She's hard-coded 144 elements, and I think she could do it more easily with an array.

Here's the code I'm trying to make an array out of.

(Is this appropriate for an array? Would it be a multi-dimensional array?)

```
stroke(color1)
circle(-200, -200, circsize);
circle(-100, -200, circsize);
circle(0, -200, circsize);
circle(100, -200, circsize);
circle(200, -200, circsize);
circle(300, -200, circsize);
circle(400, -200, circsize);
circle(500, -200, circsize);
circle(600, -200, circsize);
circle(700, -200, circsize);
circle(800, -200, circsize);
circle(900, -200, circsize);
circle(1000, -200, circsize);
circle(1100, -200, circsize);
circle(1200, -200, circsize);

circle(-200, -100, circsize);
circle(-100, -100, circsize);
circle(0, -100, circsize);
circle(100, -100, circsize);
circle(200, -100, circsize);
circle(300, -100, circsize);
circle(400, -100, circsize);
circle(500, -100, circsize);
circle(600, -100, circsize);
circle(700, -100, circsize);
circle(800, -100, circsize);
circle(900, -100, circsize);
circle(1000, -100, circsize);
circle(1100, -100, circsize);
circle(1200, -100, circsize);

circle(-200, 0, circsize);
circle(-100, 0, circsize);
circle(0, 0, circsize);
circle(100, 0, circsize);
circle(200, 0, circsize);
circle(300, 0, circsize);
circle(400, 0, circsize);
circle(500, 0, circsize);
circle(600, 0, circsize);
circle(700, 0, circsize);
circle(800, 0, circsize);
circle(900, 0, circsize);
circle(1000, 0, circsize);
circle(1100, 0, circsize);
circle(1200, 0, circsize);
```

And it continues to 1200.

```
circle(-200, 1200, circsize);
circle(-100, 1200, circsize);
circle(0, 1200, circsize);
circle(100, 1200, circsize);
circle(200, 1200, circsize);
circle(300, 1200, circsize);
circle(400, 1200, circsize);
circle(500, 1200, circsize);
circle(600, 1200, circsize);
circle(700, 1200, circsize);
circle(800, 1200, circsize);
circle(900, 1200, circsize);
circle(1000, 1200, circsize);
circle(1100, 1200, circsize);
circle(1200, 1200, circsize);
```

Comment: Create an array of points and loop over them? `const arr = [[0, 1200], [-100, 500], ...]` and `for (const [x, y] of points) circle(x, y, circsize)`?

Answer (score 0):

You certainly could place these position values in an array, and the best solution would be a multi dimensional array (that is, an array of arrays, since JavaScript doesn't have any specialized support for multi dimensional arrays). However, That is still a lot of manual typing, and you have to then iterate over the array with a loop, so it seems like this would be a good time to introduce the concept of nested loops.

Basically you are drawing 15 rows of circles, so you can have one loop that runs one iteration per row, and then you are drawing 15 circles per row, so you can have a loop that runs one iteration per circle.

There are two ways to implement this approach, one would be using a `for (const ... of ...)` loop to iterate over an array of positions, and the other would be a `for (let i = -200; i < ...; i += 100)`. Here's what each of these would look like:

```
const positions = [-200, -100, 0, 100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900, 1000, 1100, 1200];

for (const y of positions) {
  for (const x of positions) {
    circle(x, y, circsize);
  }
}
```

And the `for (;;)` version:

```
for (let y = -200; y <= 1200; y += 100) {
  for (let x = -200; x <= 1200; x += 100) {
    circle(x, y, circsize);
  }
}
```

Which approach you choose to take will largely depend on how much you want to prioritize introducing the array concept, and perhaps how comfortable your student is with the more complicated syntax of the for loop with the initializer, condition, and increment steps.